# my hard disk is too noisy (always making clicking noise)

Tags: sound, hard-drive, noise

I am fairly new to Linux and I am noticing my hard disk is constantly churning over with clicking sounds. I've tried various sites to fix this problem, but have been unsuccessful.

I've tried: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-reduce-hard-drive-s-acoustic-noise-level
and: http://www.computercorrect.com/2011/operating-systems/linux/ubuntu/fix-for-constant-hard-drive-clicking-in-ubuntu/

This site that it's a 'parking problem.' "

> You hard drive has heads that read the surface of the platters, and
>   excessive head parking in Ubuntu Linux and its variants is not
>   uncommon – especially on laptops running on battery power.

"

Is there an easy way to fix this problem? Can someone show me step by step? Is there a program that I can download?

In Windows I never had problems like this. I want to stay with Linux generally and more specifically Ubuntu.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The second link has a solution to the head parking problem. Have you tried it? What was the result? If not, then why?

Comment: with the last terminal line I typed in "sudo touch /etc/pm/power.d/95hdparm-apm"
touch: cannot touch '/etc/pm/power.d/95hdparm-apm': No such file or directory

Comment: My two cents: 1. This problem is worse, if the power supply is not quite sufficient; 2. This problem was bad with a new 4 TB (3.5 ") HDD, and disappeared gradually after running a few hours. Maybe the friction was high in the beginning (and reduced after running during those hours).

Comment: @sudodus -- I've had my computer for about 2 weeks now and have left on many times for a few hours and it has not changed. It's a desktop computer as well. i7 hp. No problems of power supply. I am surprised it happened to you though too, but you are lucky the problem went away, good for you, but I feel sad. :(

Comment: You can tell the vendor about the problem and say you want to replace the HDD within the warranty. (There could be something wrong with it.)

Comment: Your "cannot touch" error message is because you don't have an `/etc/pm/power.d` (and possibly also `/etc/pm`) directory. To resolve this, run `sudo mkdir -p /etc/pm/power.d` and then try the `touch` command again.

Comment: @DaveSherohman -- Yeah, this didn't work unfortunately. I might have to do what sudodus said. I've tried speeding up my hard disk with the disk program. I even tried the log files to see if too many files were being written to it. I couldn't even open it, so I uninstalled it. (It's either the venor, or someone has a great answer on here (that would be awesome) or back to the awful Windows cult... :( ...By the way, I tried to download hdparm but I have no idea how to install those "tar. gz" installation files. Be great if you could show me that too.

Comment: backup immediately. using `ddrescue`

Answer (score 0):

Changing hard disk acoustic level helped me:

```
sudo hdparm -M 128 /dev/sda
```